# hasNextInt() returns false for String input parsed

Tags: java, parseint

Hi I have a problem with reading a text-file:

I load into Java a file called huizen.txt,  which is the following: (I put it in workspace, C:\, src, bin, in Files in the project itself and on the desktop, still dont know where to put it correctly)

```
3
Emmalaan 23
3051JC Rotterdam
7 kamers
prijs 300000
Javastraat 88
4078KB Eindhoven
3 kamers
prijs 50000
Javastraat 93
4078KB Eindhoven
4 kamers
prijs 55000
```

Now I want (in the end......) to say loop for 3 times through a read-method for appartments since 3 is the number of appartments. But when I try: `int NumberOfAppartmentsInList = scanner.nextInt();` , this does not work! I get false even for `scanner.hasNextInt()`, even when I try `NumberOfAppartmentsInList = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0))` when I create an arraylist for the string lines..

Can anyone help me out?

Tnx in advance!

Grtz (code below)

```
public static Portefeuille read(String infile) throws Exception
{

    Portefeuille protonX = new Portefeuille();
    ArrayList<String> huizen = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("huizen.txt");

    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
    huizen.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    String infil3 = huizen.toString();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(infil3);

    if (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
    int aantal = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(aantal);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

    ArrayList<Woning> list = new ArrayList<Woning>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        list.add(Woning.read(scan));
    }

    scan.close();
    sc.close();
    return protonX;
}
```

Comment: This is my code so far:

Comment: can you put this code into your question? It will be way more readable then.

Comment: the 4 I put there because nextInt didnt work, just for test!

Comment: Woning has the same issue because it also requires an int as input variable.. When I make the Apparment (Woning) objects myself it gives no problem, but when I use the scanner It cant read ints...

Answer (score 0):

You did not read the data in the right order, I guess. Plus huizen.toString() will not give you the sum of all strings.

So the one way to fix it might be like this:

public static Portefeuille read(String infile) throws Exception
{

```
Portefeuille protonX = new Portefeuille();
ArrayList<String> huizen = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner("huizen.txt");

while (sc.hasNext())
{
huizen.add(sc.nextLine());
}

String infil3   = "";

for (String h : huizen)
{
    infil3 += h + "\n";
}

Scanner scan = new Scanner(infil3);

if (scan.hasNextInt())
{
int aantal = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(aantal);
}
else{
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}

ArrayList<Woning> list = new ArrayList<Woning>();
for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
{
    list.add(Woning.read(scan));
}

scan.close();
sc.close();
return protonX;
```

}

Comment: Okay I changed the scanner module call and made it work for that, but still when I try to reach the file: String huizen = "C:\\huizen.txt"; Scanner scanner = new Scanner(huizen);
  System.out.println(scanner.hasNextInt()); --- It returns 'false'.. Am I doing something wrong with reading-in the file?

Comment: yes, there are more issues there. toString() conversion being the main problem.

Comment: Ok thanks! But for the for-loop itself: when declaring i_max for the number on top of the textfile (3), the declaration of this in the if-loop cannot go outside of this loop, so how can I set the number of adds of Woning's to 3, whilst not reading over that 'line' to read the correct 4 string-lines into a Woning instance? Thanks very much

Comment: yeah, I have changed it now. Actually you can do it your way, the only problem was the correct conversion of the ArrayList to one big String. Also, when you are looping, you have to loop over the aantal variable, not over the number of lines in the Woning component (because that should be taken care of by Woning.read(scan).

Comment: Wonderful, looks a lot cleaner indeed :) Will test it now, thanks again! I hope there are no problems of reading any type in this String input by the Scanner-class. Goedenacht!

Comment: Insgelijks :) If your Woning class has read() method implemented correctly, there shouldn't be a problem, otherwise you would have to check that too.

Comment: if (scan.hasNextInt())
  {
  int aantal = scan.nextInt(); combined with ArrayList<Woning> list = new ArrayList<Woning>();
  for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++)

Comment: nextInt in huizen.txt is 3, when reading with scanner.nextInt() or converting to String-array; put that to aantal and then give that as a value for the number of loops for adding Woning's, skipping the value-line itself since it was already called (so skip to nextX) -> is my way of thinking here, any faults in this reasoning?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. Once you read scan.nextInt, you already got past that value. Scan moves from the beginning to end of whatever it reads.

Comment: I solved it for the file: I did not properly write the initial Adress function and I used nextLine() constantly instead of next(), since the information was not under eachother but next to, or sometimes next, which I should have calculated beforehand.

Comment: But now when testing the final Driver I get double printouts for 1 Woning instance: it prints first the adress details (which are read through a scanner by the class-method Adress.read(scanner), and then the Woning details (read by Woning.read(scanner), so double the adress! In my loop (my guess), the Woning in the huizen.txt is read as Adress + Woning, and not as a single woning, as a cause of Adress and Woning both accessing the same text at the same time. Does anyone have any ideas on how to privatize the adress data from the Woning.read(huizen.txt) method so it doesnt double print? Tnx!